# Conflict between Bhagwad Gita & Garuda Puran regarding the Atma/Soul

Tags: bhagavad-gita, atma, naraka, garuda-purana

In Bhagwad gita, Lord Shri Krishna said that

> Our soul/spirit is so small even smallar then the size of an atom. We cannot see, harm, or kill it and it is immortal.

But *Garuda Purana* explains about all kinds of punishments given to us after death depending upon our deeds performed in our life span, before the next birth.

So there is a conflict if the size of the spirit is smaller than the atom, then how it is possible to give these kind of punishments? like roasting in hot oil tank by Yama, Kinkaras etc.

Comment: As Pradip elucidates in his beautiful answer that Gita talks about the Supreme Soul or divinity, while the Puran talks about the subtle body. Ofcourse! The Bhagawad Gita speaks about the immortal knowledge of the soul, whereas the Garuda Puran talks about the innumerable misery that occurs as a result of association with the body! The purport of the Gita is to transcend body and mind, whereas the Puran is to elucidate the laws applicable to human beings.

Comment: Haaa, I used to hear that stories when I was a kid that if we do bad, we will be fried by Yama etc etc :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no conflict. Gita is talking about the Atman. Garuda Purana is talking about the linga sarira (also known as sukshma sarira) or the subtle body.

The human body and personality are contained in 5 sheaths according to Vedanta:

- Annamaya kosha
- Pranamaya Kosha
- Manomaya Kosha
- Vignanamaya Kosha
- Anandamaya Kosha

Of these koshas, *Annamaya Kosha* is the gross body. The next three koshas make up the subtle body or linga sarira. The last *Anandamaya Kosha* is the causal body or karana sarira.

> There are five kosas or sheaths in which the Self is manifested as the
> ego or the jivatman. The first of them consists of **food**. Other
> sheaths consists of **prana** or life, **manas** or instinctive and
> perceptual consciousness, **vijnana** or intelligence and **ananda**
> or bliss. These five principles of matter, life, consciousness,
> thought and bliss are found in the world of non-ego. Anna or food is
> the radiant, the viraj, which is perceptible by the senses, the
> physical. According to Suresvara, life, consciousness and intelligence
> constitute the subtle self, the sutratman and bliss is the causal
> sheath, the karana kosa.

**Commentary on Taittiriya Upanishad II.1.1 by S. Radhakrishnan in The Principal Upanishads**

After these 5 koshas lie the Atman. The mind is a small part of the subtle body. Even ghosts have subtle and causal bodies.

Comment: What do you mean by subtle body, can you please explain this.
Atma itself is a subtle element

Comment: The human body and personality are contained in 5 sheaths according to Vedanta:Annamaya kosha, Pranamaya Kosha, Manomaya Kosha, Vignanamaya Kosha and Anandamaya Kosha. Of these koshas, Annamaya Kosha is the gross body. The next three koshas make up the subtle body. The last Anandamaya Kosha is the causal body. After these 5 koshas lie the Atman.

Comment: ok thanks bro after googling about these terms I got your point.

Comment: One more thing what about the ghosts, these are atmans or amonng these three bodies?

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay its better to add details in answer rather then comment.

Comment: Ghosts must also have subtle, causal bodies and the Atman.

Comment: They must be giving a body to atman as we have now and then the torture.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay- Is the linga sahrira also known as Sukshma sharira?

Comment: The ghosts and pechas are the jivas who get trapped in the Manomaya Kosha due to their unfulfilled wishes and their lust for material objects, this is one type of suffering of hell also given to those who do atmahatya(suicide).

Comment: yes, linga sarira is also known as sukshma sarira.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay You should cite sources, preferably Hindu scripture.